# Internet explorer 7 iframe is moving when clicking on link

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, iframe, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem with an iframe, which moves the parent frame layout around when clicking on an anchor(or the javascript link which has an anchor, not sure)
The whole iframe moves to the left of the page.
demo on [removed, sorry], click on a link in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to be an answer to this problem.

I discovered that:
 **"It is not a bug. It is a feature"**

[Source](http://www.scriptwell.net/fastweb/flyinsoup.html)

Comment: no, have solved it by using tables instead of divs in the page itself, which solved it, but it's not nice..